# Mootools detecting partial dom change event

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

Good morning,
i have a mootools class with the event 'beforeunload' associate to the window object.
i need to add similar event when my partial dom container change/remove.
There is a way to intercept this event?
This is my class code:

```
var Push = new Class({

    Implements: [Events],

    attachPushClassEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        window.addEvent('beforeunload', function(event){
            // do something
        });              
    },

    initialize : function(domContainer) {
       this.container = domContainer;
       self.attachPushClassEvents();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain better "similar event "? do you mean when a dom element changes or is removed?

Comment: he wants a dom contentChange event, but on element level. in modern browsers you can use `MutationObserver()` API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - otherwise dirty checking... maybe bubbling from `document::onContentChange`

Comment: if you can guarantee that only you will detach the element from the DOM via an API you can fire the events manually, though. like `myclass.prototype.destroy = function(){ this.fireEvent('beforedestroy'); this.element.destroy(); return this.fireEvent('destroy'); }`

Comment: I solved with MutationObserver.
Thanks